# How to Convert ES5 into ES6 using Babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

As you all know, now we have 100% support for ES6 in most of the browsers. I am trying to split my bundles into two ES5 and ES6 and get smaller bundle with ES6.

I tried and I was able to see 2 different bundles. But I did not see much of a  difference in size. Because, Babel is trying not converting ES5 code into ES6 which is not giving much gain in the bundle size.

Is there any feature in Babel to transpile ES5 code into ES6?

Comment: Try out lebab. Does the opposite of babel. https://github.com/lebab/lebab

Comment: Any ES5 code is valid ES6 code. And Babel only transpiles newer features into older equivalent code, not the other way round (detecting patterns in ES5 that could be expressed differently in ES6). You should aim to write ES6 as the source.

Comment: While you *could* transpile down ESNext to ES6, it would probably be a lot easier for development just to have *one* target. The bundle size could be smaller, but I'm doubtful it'd be worth the effort to detect compatibility before sending the appropriate bundle

Comment: There is no automated conversion of ES5 to ES6.  ES5 runs just fine in ES6.  That's not something that Babel does.

Comment: @jake - I tried lebab but ended with lot of errors. Do you have any project where lebab is configured?

Comment: @RoopPadala got an answer ?